# c# HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse generic stuff

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am playing around with an app using `HttpWebRequest` to dialog with a web server.

I followed standard instructions I found on the web to build my request function that I tried to make as generic as possible (I try to get a unique method regardless of the method:  PUT, POST, DELETE, REPORT, ...)

When I submit a "REPORT" request, I get two access logs on my server:

1) I get response 401 after following line is launched in debugger

```
reqStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body), 0, body.Length);
```

2) I get response 207 (multi-get, which is what I expect) after passing the line calling `Request.GetResponse();`

Actually, it seems to be the `Request.GetRequestStream()` line that is querying the server the first time, but the request is only committed once passing the `reqStream.Write(...)` line...

Same for PUT and DELETE, the `Request.GetRequestStream()` again generates a 401 access log on my server whereas the `Request.GetResponse();` returns code 204.

I don't understand why for a unique request I have **two** server access logs, especially one that seems to be doing nothing as it always returns code 401... Could anybody explain what is going on? Is it a flaw in my code or a bad design due to my attempt to get a generic code for multiple methods?

Here is my full code:

```
public static HttpWebResponse getHttpWebRequest(string url, string usrname, string pwd, string method, string contentType, 
                                       string[] headers, string body) {
  // Variables.
  HttpWebRequest Request;
  HttpWebResponse Response;
  //
  string strSrcURI = url.Trim();
  string strBody = body.Trim();
  try {
    // Create the HttpWebRequest object.
    Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strSrcURI);

    // Add the network credentials to the request.
    Request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usrname.Trim(), pwd);

    // Specify the method.
    Request.Method = method.Trim();

    // request headers
    foreach (string s in headers) {
      Request.Headers.Add(s);
    }

    // Set the content type header.
    Request.ContentType = contentType.Trim();

    // set the body of the request...
    Request.ContentLength = body.Length;
    using (Stream reqStream = Request.GetRequestStream()) {
      // Write the string to the destination as a text file.
      reqStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body), 0, body.Length);
      reqStream.Close();
    }

    // Send the method request and get the response from the server.
    Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

    // return the response to be handled by calling method...
    return Response;
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("Web API error: " + e.Message, e);
  }
```

Comment: `reqStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body), 0, body.Length);` this assumes your UTF-8 string will map to exactly the same number of bytes which although may work, is technically wrong.